# c# script task SSIS include/access dll from reference not in GAC

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, dll, ssis

I have:

1. SSIS/.dtsx package with a script task in SSIS that I added references to.  It works fine locally (assuming the .dlls are in the GAC).

   2. When depolying on the server it failes (assuming the .dlls are NOT references in the GAC) and I can not add them.
   3. The SSIS package is stored in Integration Services on the SQL server in the Stored Packages - MSDB
   4. The job runs on a schedule
   5. I do not have access or the ability to add .dlls or add items to the GAC on the server.

What I need to do is find a way to include the .dll in the script task inside the SSIS package so that the References point to those .dlls instead of any in the GAC.

I searched quite a bit and could not find a way to do this.  Is it even possible?  If so what/how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Locally it does work, in server it cannot find a required reference. what referenced dll is missing? you know it?

Once you know what dll you need, get a copy of it and, even if you cannot install it on the server GAC, you can deploy it in the same folder you deploy your executable.

At runtime, your executable will first try to load the dll from the same folder, if not found, it will try searching in GAC.

Comment: Its in an SSIS package that is stored in SQL serve, so I can not deploy the .dll with the package